# Table design for "cordoned off" tables to avoid locking?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have an application where there are groups of users who rarely to never see or interact with each others' data, even though it's in the same tables. Effectively they could all be running separate SQL Server databases 95% of the time. But I don't want to have a separate database for each because that introduces its own issues (the other 5% of the time, for example).

How can I design so that there is never (or minimal) "locking between groups" and queries are fast? That is, users are "cordoned off" from each other, in terms of ideally never needing to lock the same resource (index, key, etc.)?

For example imagine a table to hold "sales orders":

```
create table SalesOrder (
    UserGroupId int not null foreign key references UserGroup(UserGroupId),
    SalesOrderId int not null,
    DatePlaced datetime not null,
    primary key (UserGroupId, SalesOrderId)
)
```

Initially I only had the primary key on SalesOrderId as an IDENTITY but now I see regularly an insert that locks the primary key, causing an insert from a user in another group to wait. Even though there will almost never be a query which would scan the entire table or have any false results due to the record from "the other group" being there or not. So it all seems very wasteful.

Should I switch to the above design where the keys all involve UserGroupId?

Likewise imagine queries involving DatePlaced. Group A only ever wants "their" records so should the index be (UserGroupId, DatePlaced)? To avoid having to uselessly scan through other users' sales orders.

That is, essentially every primary key, foreign key, index, etc. always has UserGroupId as its first component?

So a table of "items" in the order (1..many) would be:

```
create table SalesOrderItem(
    GroupId int not null foreign key references UserGroup(UserGroupId),
    SalesOrderId int not null,
    SalesOrderItemId int not null,
    primary key(GroupId, SalesOrderItemId),
    foreign key (GroupId, SalesOrderId) references SalesOrder(UserGroupId, SalesOrderId)
)
```

Hope that makes sense and thanks for your help!

Comment: sounds like you have a different issue if colliding inserts are causing a problem. Inserts colliding with select on the other hand... make sure the clustered index is the same. Also consider snapshot isolation to prevent select queries locking while avoiding dirty reads.

Comment: Thanks Ben! What seems to happen is I insert a record which triggers the identity constraint to generate a new PK value. But that locks the entire table for the duration of the transaction the insert was wrapped in, which could be unfortunately a fairly long time. Which then causes "select" statements to wait. So the point is to force SQL Server to only lock "part" of the table, not the "entire" table for all the operations. That would reduce dramatically the contention. Does the key redesign actually do that is the core of my question?

Comment: No, generating identities doesn't lock the table. Something else is going on. The big issue here though, is you have a long running transaction. *Don't have long running transactions*.

Comment: To be clear, the identity won't lock the table, but the insert will at least lock the row, and the index pages. Ensure row locking is turned on for the table and all the indexes. *and consider snapshot isolation*.

Comment: Since there are a lot of other things going on it is impossible to give you better help without knowing what those things are!